# What is the best way to Serialize/Deserialize Class Objects in Python?

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization, pickle

I am trying to log some data from units that I am working with for long term and short term data collection and storage.

**Should I use the json library or the pickle library and then how do I load the units' data from a file, be able to manipulate it, add units, etc., and then save the updated data back to the file?**

Here is a detailed explanation of my problem and where I am stuck:

For each unit I have some data in a class object:

```
unit_1.name = 'unit_1'
unit_1.folder = 'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\1'
unit_1.serial_number = 1
unit_1.offsets = [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 ...]
unit_1.status = 'Open'
etc
```

I would like to store these objects for long term storage (so in a file), but I also need to be able to access them from the command line as a class object by doing something like this:

```
>python
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>from file import unit_log
>unit_log.load()
>unit_1.serial_number
1
```

and I would like to create new units like this:

```
>unit_2 = unit_log(2)
```

which would create the other fields in the **init** module of the class.
After which I could save the units that I created or modified by doing something like:

```
>unit_log.save()
```

and it would save all the units to the file. Here is the code for the class:

```
file.py

class unit_log:
    def __init__ (self, serial_number):
        self.serial_number = serial_number;
        self.unit_name = 'unit_'+str(serial_number)
        self.status = 'Open';
        self.offsets = [];
        self.folder = 'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\' + str(serial_number)
    @classmethod
    def load (self):
        #Something that loads the data
    @classmethod
    def save (self):
        #Something that saves the data
```

My current understanding is that what I am trying to do is called serialization/deserialization and that there are a couple different ways to do this (the big ones being the pickle library and the json library).

My question is: How do I deserialize a json file (or a pickle file) into a bunch of class objects?
I am assuming the json file would look something like this:

```
unit_logs.json
{
    unit_1:{
    {
    "unit_name": "unit_1",
    "serial_number": 1,
    "status": "Open",
    "offsets": [],
    "folder": "C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\1"
    }
    unit_2...
    unit_3...
    ...
}
```

and I would load in the file using `log = json.load(unit_logs.json)`. I would like to then have a

```
for unit in log:
    unit["unit_name"] = unit_log(unit)
```

but that is not how declaring a variable works.

I believe that the pickle library works similarly but I am less familiar with that one.

**Should I use the json library or the pickle library and then how do I load the units' data from a file, be able to manipulate it, add units, etc., and then save the updated data back to the file?**

Comment: why do you want to use pickle? your json looks simple, use json it's faster than pickle

Comment: I just read that pickle is another option. I would rather use json as I know more about it, I just do not know how to deserialize the json file into class objects as I described above.

Answer (score 0):

`pickle` library is easy to use

Dump an object `obj` to file:

```
import pickle

with open(f_path, "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(obj, f)
```

Load a pickle file:

```
with open(f_path, "rb") as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```

Then you can change `obj` and write it again to file

In case you want to load the same pickle file several times and have different objects you can just:

```
N=<number of copies>

with open(f_path, "rb") as f:
    obj_list = [pickle.load(f) for _ in range(N)]
```

Now you can edit each object in `obj_list` separately, and if you want to save its state to a pickle file, you use `pickle.dump` as described above.

So you can have a "template" pickle file to load from, and then edit the objects as you want.

Comment: this does not answer the question of how to write all of the units in at the same time in the load module

Comment: What do you mean? Your serialized objects can also be a list of objects

Comment: If I am understanding your code correctly then 'obj' would be all of the units. How would I go about changing one unit? I was thinking that when you deserialize the units, they would somehow each have their own variable, such that you could do something along the lines of '>unit_1.open_folder()' or 'unit_2.log_data()'. How else could you write and manipulate certain units if they dont all have their own variable name?

Comment: ive been reading some more and maybe the answer is to have dynamic variables created for each unit? Not really sure how this works in practice though.

Comment: Each time you load from the pickle file, you get a brand new different object, so you can have an array of objects or put your objects in other collection. Added that in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to you use json, just try this:

```py
json.dumps(unit_log_instance.__dict__)
```

Comment: could you elaborate on how to implement this into the code above? what is unit_log_instance? This also does not answer the question of how to create each unit's class object at once.

Answer (score -1):

Here is something you might useful. There is a Python package available to smartly construct objects from YAML/JSON/dicts, and is actively being developed and expanded. (*full disclosure, I am a co-author of this package*, see [here](http://blog.zipfian.science/tech/2020-11-20-pickle-rick-open-sourced.html))

**EDIT**:

Now, in your case, you might consider using it as follows:

As a YAML file (`filename.yaml`) (or JSON), the following could be defined:

```yaml
name: 'unit_1'
folder: 'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\1'
serial_number: 1
offsets: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 ]
status: 'Open'
```

Loading this as a Python object from file is achieved:

```sh
>> python
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> from pickle_rick import PickleRick
> unit_1 = PickleRick('./filename.yaml')
> unit_1.serial_number
1
```

Changes can then be made and saved to file again:

```sh
> unit_1.serial_number += 41
> unit_1.serial_number
42
> unit_1.to_yaml_file('./filename.yaml')
```

Or as JSON file.

Now, to have more than one *unit*, consider a structure as this:

```yaml
units:
    - name: 'unit_1'
      folder: 'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\1'
      serial_number: 1
      offsets: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 ]
      status: 'Open'

    - name: 'unit_2'
      folder: 'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\1'
      serial_number: 1
      offsets: [0.00, 0.00 ]
      status: 'Closed'
```

Then this can be loaded as a list of units:

```sh
>> python
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> from pickle_rick import PickleRick
> all_units = PickleRick('./filename.yaml', deep=True)
> all_units.units[0].serial_number
1
```

**Original post**:

Install:

`pip install pickle-rick`

Use:

Define a YAML or JSON string (or file).

```yaml
BASIC:
 text: test
 dictionary:
   one: 1
   two: 2
 number: 2
 list:
   - one
   - two
   - four
   - name: John
     age: 20
 USERNAME:
   type: env
   load: USERNAME
 callable_lambda:
   type: lambda
   load: "lambda: print('hell world!')"
 datenow:
   type: lambda
   import:
     - "from datetime import datetime as dd"
   load: "lambda: print(dd.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))"
 test_function:
   type: function
   name: test_function
   args:
     x: 7
     y: null
     s: hello world
     any:
       - 1
       - hello
   import:
     - "math"
   load: >
     def test(x, y, s, any):
       print(math.e)
       iii = 111
       print(iii)
       print(x,s)
       if y:
         print(type(y))
       else:
         print(y)
       for i in any:
         print(i)
```

Then use it as an object.

```sh
>> from pickle_rick import PickleRick

>> config = PickleRick('./config.yaml', deep=True, load_lambda=True)

>> config.BASIC.dictionary
{'one' : 1, 'two' : 2}

>> config.BASIC.callable_lambda()
hell world!
```

You can define Python functions, load additional data from other files or REST APIs, environmental variables, and then write everything out to YAML or JSON again.

This works especially well when building systems that require structured configuration files, or in notebooks as interactive structures.

**There is a security note to using this. Only load files that are trusted, as any code can be executed, thus stay clear of just loading anything without knowing what the complete contents are.**

The package is called PickleRick and is available here:

- [Documentation](http://docs.zipfian.science/pickle-rick/index.html)
- [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pickle-rick/)
- [Github](https://github.com/Zipfian-Science/pickle-rick)

Comment: Can you perhaps adjust this to at least remotely match the question setup? While this seems like a viable *backend* for what the OP wants to do, it also seems to require just as much boilerplate as the other backends the OP already discovered.